# how to selectedindex option by value or xpath

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

iam using tampermonkey and i want to select an spicific option in a selecteindex by using value to get the element want because the website displayed in defirent languages (english....spanish...ets) and not keep the same order in the index btw he always keep the same value ....by using the value i can select the same option even if web site change languege
i already tried the calissic method but not working.

```
document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex = "2";
```

and here there is the source code in english

```html
<select id="service" name="service" class="form-control-input" autocomplete="off">
<option value="">Select Service</option>
<option value="305">yes</option>
<option value="304">two</option>
<option value="303">storm</option></select>
```

and here there is the source code in french

```html
<select id="service" name="service" class="form-control-input" autocomplete="off">
<option value="">Select Service</option>
<option value="303">orga</option>
<option value="304">deux</option>
<option value="305">oui</option></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can choose - for example - `yes` and `oui` by using an xpath expression:

```
document.evaluate("//option[@value='305']", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null )
```

The two words can be accessed in a `for` loop by

```
nodesSnapshot.snapshotItem(i).textContent
```